# Hibernate schemaupdate generates duplicate foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to upgrade hibernate 4.2.0 to 4.3.6, but the schemaupdate task fails because it generates duplicate foreign keys with the same name. It seems the previous version of hibernate also generated duplicate foreign keys, but I didn't notice it because they got different names.

The problem is with the following (simplified) classes

```
@Entity
public class Relation
{
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Parent parent;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Parent
{

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("child")
public class Child extends Parent
{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Relation> relations
}
```

The schemaupdate task generates a foreign key from relation to parent and from child to relation. But it doesn't recognize this is the same foreign key.

I have come up with three possible solutions, but I'm hoping there is a better one.

- targetEntity: Add a targetEntity=Child.class to the Relation class, but the Relation.class doesn't know the Child class. To fix this would create circular dependency.
- orm.xml: I could define the targetEntity in the orm.xml which would work.
- org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey(name = "none") on one of the two relations. This would prevent one foreign key being generated. But this would have implications for other projects using the same class. Also the hibernate version of the annotation is deprecated and the 
  javax.persistence one can not be used with mapped by.

Is there a better way to this?